# NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE drawImage in firefox

Tags: javascript, svg, drawimage

I have a code to save svg tag as png image on browser by javascript. This code works on chrome but get  "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE drawImage" error in mozila firefox. What's the problem?!

```
var svg = document.querySelector( "svg" );
var svgData = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString( svg );

var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
var ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );

var img = document.createElement( "img" );

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = "cat.png";
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  a.click();
};

img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa( svgData );
```

Comment: Does your svg data either have percentage width/height attributes or no width/height attributes. If so change them so that they are not percentages.

Comment: No width/height attributes there. I've added width/height attributes without percentage but not worked...

Comment: The problem is drawImage not works in firefox. but why?!

Comment: thanks, Robert, your comment solved my problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson yours should be the accepted answer.

Comment: According to the OP it did not fix his problem (otherwise I would have converted it to an answer). Glad it fixed yours though.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I set fill color in "path" tag of my source svg to string value like "red", "white" etc. then it works just fine. But if I set fill color with hexadecimal code like "#ffccaa" then it fails with NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE (OMG) :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please add [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you are asking for another problem.